# bringing validation fort extjs combo box

Tags: jquery, extjs, extjs4

in my extjs 4 application, i am using extjs combo like this, this combo has three values select, yes or no. by default i have to set combo value as 'select'.and also i need to alert the user if he didnt choose either yes or no.

for that i have written code like this. but it is not working.

```
xtype: 'combo',
itemId:'comboOfficial',
id:'comboOfficial',
autoSelect:true,
width:50,
queryMode: 'local',
store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    id: 0,
    fields: ['value', 'text'],
    data: [[1, 'Select'],[2, 'Yes'], [3, 'No']]  // data is local
}),
listeners: {                                                
    'select': function (combo, records, eOpts) {
        var recordSelected = combo.getStore().getAt(0); 
        alert(recordSelected);
        if(recordSelected == 1){
            alert("Please choose either 'Yes' or 'No'");
        }
    }
},
valueField: 'value',
displayField: 'text',
value: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're not actually assigning the selected record to your `recordSelected` variable.  You're always retrieving the first row from your store.  You need to replace

   ```
   var recordSelected = combo.getStore().getAt(0);
   ```

   with

   ```
   var recordSelected = records[0]; //since you don't allow multiselect, 
                                    //records will always be an array 
                                    //of length 1.
   ```
2. You can't just check if `recordSelected == 1` because recordSelect is an ExtJS object storing some data in the format specified by the model (which is created based on the fields you provided to the store.  What you want to check is the `value` of the record, which can be done by replacing

   ```
   if (recordSelected == 1) {
   ```

   with

   ```
   if (recordSelected.get('value') === 1) {
   ```

Once you've fixed both of those things, your code should work as you expect it to.

Comment: Hi Towler, thank you for your help..it worked.. and also how can i make 'select' as default value of the combo. i set value: 0 but didnt work out :-(

Comment: It seemed to work fine for me when you had `value: 1` (see http://jsfiddle.net/72Wk3/)